# Trying to recreate Fragment view after popbackstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, onbackpressed

I do the next steps:

1. Create and open a fragment (fr1) in my main Acitivty.
2. Replace the fragment for another one (and created too)(fr2)
3. Pressing button OnBackPressed and navigate to the fr1 (With pop  back stack).

   4.Trying to replace the fragment(fr1) for the same
   fr2 (another time)  but my onCreateView is not called.

I read some post this is for lifecycle fragments but did not know how to resolve it.
I need to initialize the view each time that I replace the fragment.

How can I solve it?

```
 public void navigateFragment(Fragment fragment, int fm, String tagFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tagFragment).addToBackStack(tagFragment).commit();
    }

  public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: oncreateview and onstart will not be called if u do popbackstack fragment, if you want to call oncreateview then you must replace fragment

Comment: When i Call my function navigateFragment() I create a new Fragment.
For example:

      navigateFragment(new Fragment(), 0, "Home");
But happens the same,